# How to find greatest common divisor using recursive function in Python?

Tags: python, function, recursion, input, controls

I am asked to find the greatest common divisor of integers **x** and **y** using a recursive function in Python. The condition says that: if y is equal to 0 then gcd (x,y) is **x**; otherwise gcd(x,y) is gcd(y,x%y). To try the code, I am asked to obtain two integers from the user. Here is what I tried:

```
def gcd(x , y):
    if y == 0:
        return x
    else:
        return (y, x % y)

num_one = int(input('Enter a value for x: '))
num_two = int(input('Enter a value for y: '))
if num_two == 0:
    print(num_one)
else:
    print(gcd(num_two))
```

And this is the error I get: TypeError: gcd() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this, easy change:

```
def gcd(x , y):
    if y == 0:
        return x
    else:
        return gcd(y, x % y)
```

compared with math.gcd:

```
In [1231]: gcd(127,127**2)                                                                                                                                                                                 
Out[1231]: 127

In [1232]: math.gcd(127, 127**2)                                                                                                                                                                           
Out[1232]: 127
```

and change this:

```
    print(gcd(num_two))
```

to

```
    print(gcd(num_one, num_two))
```

Full changes:

```
def gcd(x , y):
    if y == 0:
        return x
    else:
        return gcd(y, x % y)

num_one = int(input('Enter a value for x: '))
num_two = int(input('Enter a value for y: '))
if num_two == 0:
    print(num_one)
else:
    print(gcd(num_one, num_two))
```

output:

```
Enter a value for x: 46
Enter a value for y: 12
2
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer much appreciated. It solved my error. I have one question just to make sure everything is running properly. For example, I insert an input of x = 46 and y = 12 and gives me an output of (12, 10). Is everything here ok?

Comment: I get the right answer for those inputs, i updated the answer to show those values and the print

Answer (score 1):

Recursive functions call themselves. You are not calling `gcd` from within `gcd` so you haven't followed the assignment's directions.

You return 0 as a base condition so that you don't end up with a **stackoverflow** :)

Then, you call the method itself from within the containing method. In your case, you are just missing `gcd` on line 5 before the opening parenthesis.

Please read this example.

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/recursion-is-not-hard-858a48830d83/